# How to disable touch input using proximity sensor in android?

Tags: android, proximitysensor

I want to disable the input from the screen(mainly touch inputs) using proximity sensor.

The screen input must be disabled and enabled by the proximity sensor change.

I have searched many questions here, but didn't find any suitable answer.

This is the `onSensorChanged` method:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if (event.values[0] == 0) {

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sensor in 0",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 } else {

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sensor in 1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  } 
}
```

This is the code I tried but the application become crashed:

```
 Dialog overlayDialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Panel);
 overlayDialog.setCancelable(true);
 overlayDialog.show();
```

Comment: Can you please tell what you are trying to implement ? What you want to do ?

Comment: @shree202 I am developing sip dialer application. During the call, there is chance that the call get terminated by accidently touching the end call button.i want to avoid this using proximity sensor

Answer (score 0):

Try by using setClickable(false). Check this out... Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable(boolean)"setClickable")

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated.

Comment: I am really sorry, I am a newbie. I won't do this again